# Can you use python 3 with ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros, python2.7, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hear that it isn't supported according to this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/.

However, can anyone be more specific as to which parts of ROS will not work and how crucial/useful they are?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262551/can-you-use-python-3-with-ros-kinetic?/) by [hunderbergahunderberga](https://answers.ros.org/users/30519/hunderbergahunderberga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless someone has explicitly tested ROS Kinetic with Python 3, you won't find a list of known compatibility problems.

`roscore` and most of the command line tools are written in Python, so there are lots of places where brokenness may be a big problem.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2